# I have a applet for online Address Book that i have embedded in html doesn't work on html

Tags: java, html, netbeans, applet

I have a applet for online Address Book that i have embedded in html which is also communicating with oracle database(ojdbc6.jar). I am using NetBeand IDE, Ojdbc6.jar file is in library.Applet dose work fine from Netbeans, also communicate with oracle. But after putting it in html, it gives me Error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:orcle:jdbc:Driver:OracleDriver

I know that it is something with ojdbc jar file.
But can not figure out what is wrong.
Html code is as Follows:

```
   <HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <TITLE>X's Online Address Book</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY bgcolor="#DDDDFF">

     <!--

  <META name="Author" content="XXXX">
       <H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Kanchan's Online Address Book<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>
     <img src="Address.png" alt="My Masterpiece!" border="1">

        <P ALIGN=center>
       <APPLET codebase="web/WEB-INF/classes" code="InternetAddressB.class" width=800              height=400></APPLET>
         </P>

    <HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>"X's Online Address Book"</I></FONT>
      </BODY>
     </HTML>
```

PLz hel me!

Comment: 1990's HTML? I do not know what u r saying...I am runnung it in Google Chrome which is default browser on my windows machine

Comment: The HTML, besides being probably malformed, includes redundant styles (e.g. <hr> width of 100%), ancient elements (applet was deprecated in HTML 4.01) & is generally invalid (e.g. missing width/height for the image element).  [Validate it](http://validator.w3.org/)!

Answer (score 0):

> I know that it is something with ojdbc jar file.

You're part way (about 3%) there.  It needs to be added to the run-time class-path of the `applet` - in the `archive` attribute.  E.G.

```
<APPLET 
    codebase="web/WEB-INF/classes" 
    code="InternetAddressB" 
    archive="path/to/ojdbc.jar"
    width=800              
    height=400>
</APPLET>
```

**Note:**

1. The code attribute should be the fully qualified name of the class, not the file name.
2. It looks very suspicious that the codebase is set to any string that includes WEB-INF.  It  would not normally be the case that an applet has to refer to a path on the server in that way.  Further the `classes` and `lib` directories of a Java EE server are generally reserved for loose classes and archives used **exclusively** by the server.  They are not available to visitors or applets.

---

The comment from Matt was largely about using the applet element at all.  In more modern HTML/XML versions it would be more likely to use an `object` element.  OTOH it makes more sense still to use the [deployment toolkit script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to launch an applet.

Until such time you might as well stick with the `applet` element.  At least to see it work once.